# Runit: Effect of "Once" after reboot

Tags: runit

A small question: does the `once` command for `runit` activate the `run` script once every startup / session; once, and then never again unless started manually; or once, and then kept alive by `runit` after every startup / session following the current?

The reason I ask is because I want to run a small script on every startup, and was wondering if I could use `runit` for this, as this would be the simplest answer for me to set up every time I reset a system.

Comment: I use it a process two of systemd: http://smarden.org/runit/useinit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it runs the service once, then upon reboot, it switches to a regular `up` status, i.e. if the service goes down, `runit` starts it back up again.